# How to show a waiting symbol/Message while downloading and parsing 2-3 xml file in pageload (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

In the pageload event, I am accessing two/three xml files (quite big, around 512kb each) from remote server and setting up a gridview according to the parsed xml files. The page takes lots of time while loading.. I would like to show a loading message/animation while the files are downloaded and parsed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-thinking the problem. This doesn't have to be anything harder than putting a loading animation into your markup and then removing that animation when your XML files load.

It'll go something like this.

In markup:

```
<div id="loadingPanel" runat="server">
    <img src="path_to_your_loading_animation" />
</div>
```

In `Page_Load`:

```
LoadXmlFileData();
loadingPanel.InnerHtml = string.Empty;
```

Comment: It is not working... here is what I did, I have two div, one that contains the normal controls and another is this loading panel.I made the first panel invisible (display:none) , I changed nothing in pageLoad event so that only the loading panel appears.It appears but after Page_load() executes completely, not before..

Comment: @Raju Can you post the markup and C# code for the pieces you mentioned here?